How to access the the tensors between layers in keras as numpy
I have a keras model defined using Functional API. I also have its weights (.h5 file), and a single example input tensor (stored in a .npy file). I am trying to reimplement this exact model in pytorch. And i am getting a completely different result. I would like to see where did i go wrong by comparing the tensors between each layer. But i cant for the life of me extract those tensors.
It looks something like this:
def cascade_net(input_size=(640, None, 1), n_cascade=5, ...):
    kspace_input = Input(input_size, dtype='complex64', name='kspace_input')
    mask = Input(mask_shape, dtype='complex64', name='mask_input')

    zero_filled = Lambda(tf_unmasked_adj_op, output_shape=input_size, name='ifft_simple')(kspace_input)
    ...
    [long model]...

    model = Model(inputs=[kspace_input, mask], outputs=image)
    return model


initializing model like this from pretrained weights:
model = cascade_net(input_size=(None, None, 1), fastmri=True, **run_params)
model.load_weights('model_weights.h5')

and using the model like this: (i am only interested in the tensors that will be produced in this step)
cascade_reconstructed_image = model.predict_on_batch([masked_kspace_batch, mask_batch])

I tried to write a custom layer to access those tensors like this (doesnt work):
class PrintTensor(Layer):
    def call(self, inputs, name=""):
        a = tf.keras.backend.print_tensor(inputs, message=name, summarize=-1)
        if(a.shape[0] is not None):
            np.save(f"numpys/model_{name}.npy", inputs.numpy())
        return inputs

tf.Print also doesnt work.
I am not trying to print tensors to the screen i would like to save them to the disk. Is this even possible. Any help or redirection would be highly appreciated.

This has been asked many times years ago, see duplicate answer.
